# How to download entire folder in java?

Tags: java, download

I want to download entire folder/directory from server.
The folder contain files. I tried it with zip functionality but for that i need to give path till the files and not the folder path.

like -

```
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("d:\\StoreFiles\\Temp\\profile.txt"));
```

I want something like ("d:\StoreFiles") which will download all the folders in Storefiles folder and the files inside the folder.

How can i implement this?

Comment: I'd take a look at the Apache Commons IO `FileUtils.copyDirectory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this example useful for u

```
public class CopyDirectoryExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        File srcFolder = new File("c:\\mkyong");
        File destFolder = new File("c:\\mkyong-new");

        //make sure source exists
        if(!srcFolder.exists()){

           System.out.println("Directory does not exist.");
           //just exit
           System.exit(0);

        }else{

           try{
            copyFolder(srcFolder,destFolder);
           }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            //error, just exit
                System.exit(0);
           }
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    public static void copyFolder(File src, File dest)
        throws IOException{

        if(src.isDirectory()){

            //if directory not exists, create it
            if(!dest.exists()){
               dest.mkdir();
               System.out.println("Directory copied from " 
                              + src + "  to " + dest);
            }

            //list all the directory contents
            String files[] = src.list();

            for (String file : files) {
               //construct the src and dest file structure
               File srcFile = new File(src, file);
               File destFile = new File(dest, file);
               //recursive copy
               copyFolder(srcFile,destFile);
            }

        }else{
            //if file, then copy it
            //Use bytes stream to support all file types
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest); 

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int length;
                //copy the file content in bytes 
                while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
                   out.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                in.close();
                out.close();
                System.out.println("File copied from " + src + " to " + dest);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, please when copying other people's code, always provide attribution. It's required and it's the classy thing to do. http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-copy-directory-in-java/

Answer (score 2):

How about this? It recursively going in the directory and downloading:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
       directoryDownloader(new File("/Users/eugene/Desktop"));
  }

  private static void directoryDownloader(File input){
       if(input.isDirectory()){
           for(File file : input.listFiles()){
               directoryDownloader(file);
           }
       } else {
           downloadFile(input);
       }
}

 private static void downloadFile(File someFile){
     System.out.println("Downloading file : " + someFile.getPath());
 }
```

P.S. Implement the downloadFile how you want.

Comment: Thank you MadProgrammer,Sujay,aravindKrishna,Eugene for suggestions and examples, Really helped a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking at `Apache Commons IO` FileUtils to copy directories. It's pretty easy to use. [Have a look at the javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)

Some of the useful methods that might come in handy (*note that there are several ones available*):

- `copyDirectory(File srcDir, File destDir)`
- `copyDirectory(File srcDir, File destDir, FileFilter filter`)