# Create folder in the user's desktop using java/JSF

Tags: jsf

I am using jaxbe jar to create a folder containing a number of xml files.

But when the application was deployed ,the folder was created in the server's machine.

How to create it in the client side instead of the server side.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Offer them as a download

Comment: Thank you. I will try to follow the tips in this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067301/how-to-download-entire-folder-in-java cause i did't find an alternative in JSF or PrimeFaces.